Calculating the Expected Score of a Simple Game
I've come up with a simple game that is relevant to a personal project I'm working on and would appreciate some help with calculating an interesting statistic.
Suppose we play a game with the following rules:

There is a board with 9 open spots that each start with 0 points.
The player starts with 3 turns.
Each turn, one of the open spots (chosen randomly) will gain 1 point. After which each open spot will have a 10% chance of closing. A closed spot no longer gets points and is closed for the rest of the game.
Whenever a spot closes, the number of turns is reset back to 3. The game ends when you run out of turns or when all 9 spots close.
At the end of the game you add the points in all of the closed spots to get a final score.

My question is this: What is the expected score in this game? And more specifically, what is the expected score per closed spot?
Here was my approach:

I made a markov matrix with 40 states (0-9 spots closed and 0-3 turns remaining gives 40 total states). Using this matrix I could calculate the distribution of the number of closed spots, the average number of turns the game would last, and the average number of turns it takes to start from any transient state and end in any absorbing state. Since 1 point is added to the board each turn, I could take the average number of turns divided by 9 to get the average points per spot. This is close but it is not the average points per closed spot, which is different because as the game progresses you are less likely to continue playing and get the higher points in the open spots thus skewing these two averages.


I made a simulation of this game and recorded the average number of points across the whole board, and just across the closed spots. My calculation matched exactly for the average points across the whole board, but as expected the average points for just closed spots was lower (about 46% of my calculated number).


I believe I have a good set up and a lot of relevant information, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I think I need to condition on a spot being closed before calculating its expected points or try and calculate the average number of turns that it takes for a spot to close, assuming it does. Any help would be greatly appreciated!


Does the player do something on their turn, or does the turn consist solely of watching the random updates as described?

@GregMartin The turn is just watching random updates - it might not be the most exciting game but it is entirely random.

Honestly, this feels like a situation where a solid simulations will be much easier than a closed-form analysis and just as helpful.

@GregMartin I agree with you, my simulation ran 1 billion games in about 5 minutes which was plenty of trials for a good degree of accuracy. However I plan on adjusting the values in the game (such as number of spots and probability of closing) as well as making a few mechanics more complicated (different starting states or different amount of points added). For my purposes it would be very convenient to have a closed form solution as I would like to see the results as I work. It's also an interesting question to me and I enjoy seeing these medium difficulty probability problems worked out.
